# NSFetchedResultsController with complicate predicate

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm developing the app with `UICollectionView`.
It's collection of events arranged by date. I'm using `NSFetchedResultsController` to fetch data from DB. But I need to fetch current and future events + 2 past events.
For `NSFetchRequest` I'm using `NSCompoundPredicate`

```
NSPredicate *nextPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"startAt >= %@", [NSDate date]];
NSPredicate *previousPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"startAt < %@", [NSDate date]];
NSCompoundPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates: @[nextPredicate, previuosPredicate]];
fetchRequest.predicate = resultPredicate;
```

And I have no idea how to limit `previousPredicate` to receive only 2 items.

Comment: You can use `setFetchLimit` to limit the number of items returned but that works on the whole request, so you might have to look at splitting the requests and combing the results somehow. Also you'll need to add a `NSSortDescriptor` to ensure you get the 2 closest to today

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the date of **current event** than create a method that return date of the last event to fetch and then set the predicate on the main `NSFetchRequest` to that date.

```
 -(NSDate *)dateOfPastEvent{
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"EntityName" inManagedObjectContext:_mainContext];
    [request setEntity:entity];

    NSSortDescriptor *sortDesc = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"startAt" ascending:NO];
    [request setSortDescriptors:@[sortDesc]];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *array = [_mainContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];


    __block NSDate *pastEventDate;

    [array enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop){

        if ([obj valueForKey:@"startAt"] == currentEventDate) {
            if (array.count >= idx+2) {
                pastEventDate = [[array objectAtIndex:idx+2] valueForKey:@"startAt"];
                *stop = YES;
            }

        }
    }];


    return pastEventDate;

}
```

**Now set the predicate for the above returned date**

```
  NSFetchRequest *requestForController = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
  NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"EntityName" inManagedObjectContext:_mainContext];
    [requestForController setEntity:entity];

  NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"startAt >= %@", [self dateOfPastEvent]];
```